# Highlight Pointer Position

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a strange Requierment for a Task. In gernerall terms, i need to prepare Windows PCs for Presentations with a PowerShell Script and one of the Requierments is to activate the "hightlight pointer position if ctrl is hit" function in the extended pointer settings.

My first idea was to change the reg-key but if that even works, i think it would be linked to a PC-Restart. I allready tryed to change the Value of the key after finding the diffrenece in the on and off state of the function but i cant force it to "refresh the setting" or it simply does not work.

Any ideas, workaround or the like would be appriciated.

The function is controlled by the Reg-Key HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop - UserPrefernecesMask

Comment: Does [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-change-the-mouse-pointer-scheme/) solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'Mouse Sonar' function can be enabled or disabled using the `SystemParametersInfo` function inside `user32.dll`.

To use that in PowerShell, add a bit of CSharp:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class MouseSonar {
    public const uint SPI_SETMOUSESONAR = 0x101D;
    public const uint SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
    public const uint SPIF_SENDCHANGE = 0x02;
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int SystemParametersInfo (uint uAction, uint uParam, bool lpvParam, uint fuWinIni);
    public static void SetSonar (bool Enable) {
        SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETMOUSESONAR, 0, Enable, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
    }
}
'@
```

and use it like this:

```
# turn Mouse Sonar on
[MouseSonar]::SetSonar($true)

# to switch Mouse Sonar off again:
[MouseSonar]::SetSonar($false)
```

No need to restart the computer, this works immediately.